# How to enable week range in datepicker

Tags: jquery

My requirement is:
I have to display only thursdays in the first twenty weeks of every year in datepicker. How to do that? Please help me out as i  am using jquery first time in my code.

Comment: Is there something you have tried yet and got stuck?? May be you can include the attempted solutions in your question, why they didn't work!

Comment: $(#date).datepicker(options);
beforeshowday: function(date){
return ([date,getDay() == 4],"");
}

Comment: I can show thursday of every week..But i want to restrict it only for first twenty weeks and disable all days for the remaining weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Referring: [Show week number with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765767/show-week-number-with-javascript)

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}   


$('#inputId').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function (date) {
       if (date.getWeek() <= 20 && date.getDay() == 4) {
           return [true, ''];
       }
       return [false, ''];
   }
});
```