# Datepicker insert date and week in field

Tags: javascript, insert, datepicker, field

I hope that one of you experts can help me with a problem in datepicker.

I have a page with the following fields

date, week, item number, description, price

I can get the date picker to work for date and week but only if I assign datepicker to each of them.

My problem is that I want it so that when you select the date in the date field then puts datepicker automatically week number into the week field so you do not need datepicker 2 times but only once.

Unfortunately I do not have much knowledge of javascript and therefore hope there is someone who can help me

Many thanks in advance

Niels Baeklund

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765814/1671639), I learnt to get the week number using the following method.

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
    }
```

Then I have used this to get the weeknumber in the datepicker like

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var dat = new Date(date); //convert string to date
        var weekNo = dat.getWeek();
        $('#week').val(weekNo);

    }
});
```

[JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/w55hY/1/)

### **Updates:**

After a few research, I ended up with a nice solution within jQuery UI datepicker.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#week').val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/w55hY/2/)

Hope you understood.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply and it was just the solution I was looking for and it works perfectly.

I've gotten a little better understanding about datepicker :)

Thanks again
sincerely,
Niels Baeklund

Comment: @user3004377 Glad to help you, my friend :)

Comment: a small problem
In Denmark we have the date format date format 'dd / mm / yy', but when I use it is my week no NaN

I wonder if you have a go idea

Thanks in advance

Niels Baeklund