# delete from Json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
"[
"{\"StudentID\":5042,\"Status\":\"Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM\",\"Date\":\"2013-11-20\"}",    

"{\"StudentID\":5042,\"Status\":\"Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM\",\"Date\":\"2013-11-20\"}",    

"{\"StudentID\":5042,\"Status\":\"Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM\",\"Date\":\"2013-11-20\"}"]
```

I have this type of data in java script i want to delete that records which are not in current week date.

Comment: You have to parse the JSON, iterate over the resulting array and compare the value of the properties. Maybe this gives you a start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196.

Comment: I feel something wrong in your JSON, can you correct it.

Comment: dont know that this is correct or not but i am doing lots of other things with this data and Json.Parse() easily parse my above data so seems to be no issue in Json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using **`$.each()`** iterate the parsed JSON.
2) To get the week number use the below [protype method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046599/1671639)

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}
```

To use:

```
var todayWeekNo = new Date().getWeek();
```

3)To check whether they belong to same week use

```
var isEqual = (todayWeekNo == new Date(j.Date).getWeek());
```

4) If it is not equal, delete it using index.

Finally,

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}

var arr = [{
    "StudentID": 5041,
        "Status": "Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM",
        "Date": "2013-11-20"
}, {
    "StudentID": 5042,
        "Status": "Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM",
        "Date": "2013-11-20"
}, {
    "StudentID": 5043,
        "Status": "Joshua picked up  from school [0]    at 12:41PM and reached home [0] at    12:43PM",
        "Date": "2013-11-20"
}];


var todayWeekNo = new Date().getWeek();
$.each(arr, function (i, j) {
    var isEqual = todayWeekNo == new Date(j.Date).getWeek();
    if (!isEqual) {
        delete arr[i];
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6hte/)

**Updates:**

> [Since  `Delete` won't remove the element from the array it will only set the
>   element as `undefined`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/1671639)

So I tried using **`arr.splice(i, 1);`** but it was not working.  With reference to this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125989/1671639) here is an alternative approach.

```
var todayWeekNo = new Date().getWeek();
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    var isEqual = (todayWeekNo == new Date(arr[i].Date).getWeek());
    if (!isEqual) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: @Zeeshan Saleem I have updated my answer, go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Call this code to reduce as per your need.

```
function reduceJSON(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var returnObject = {};
        if(/* Your Condition Here */) {
            returnObject.push(value);
        }
    });
    return returnObject;
}

yourJSON = reduceJSON(yourJSON);
```