# Get week number and number of the day in the week from jquery ui calendar

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

How to get week number / number of the day in the week when choose date from calendar?
For example if I choose 28-May-2015, to get 22/4.  (22th week, Thursday is 4th day in this week).

Currently i got just week number (22).
The code is:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $('.pick-date').datepicker({
        showWeek: true, firstDay: 1 ,
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,



      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {


    inst.input.val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));

    }
    });
});
```

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7765814/4454454)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show week number with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765767/show-week-number-with-javascript)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Xr3/225/