# Get week of year for a specific culture

Tags: javascript, javascript-globalize

Is it possible to get week of the year in some way using [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)?

Comment: Can you not parse the date from globalize and pass it into the function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: I could. But ISO week is not the only week format. As Globalize handles most of other culture differences I were wondering if it has support for weeks too.