# Get weeks in year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment js has a function to get the number of days in a month : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/

However I could not find a function to find the number of iso weeks in a year (52 or 53).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's an answer that isn't dependent on a library. It uses a function to calculate the week in the year that 31 December falls in for the required year. If the week is 1 (i.e. 31 December is in the first week of the following year), it moves the day number lower until it gets a different value, which will be the last week of the required year.

```js
function getWeekNumber(d) {
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  d = new Date(+d);
  d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
  // Make Sunday's day number 7
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
  // Get first day of year
  var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
  var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7)
  // Return array of year and week number
  return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
}

function weeksInYear(year) {
  var month = 11,
    day = 31,
    week;

  // Find week that 31 Dec is in. If is first week, reduce date until
  // get previous week.
  do {
    d = new Date(year, month, day--);
    week = getWeekNumber(d)[1];
  } while (week == 1);

  return week;
}

[2015, 2016, 2029, new Date().getFullYear()].forEach(year =>
  console.log(`${year} has ${weeksInYear(year)} weeks`)
);
```

The *getWeekNumber* code is from here: [Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php/6117889#6117889).

#### Edit

Alternatively, if 31 December is in week 1 of the following year, then the subject year has 52 weeks and otherwise has 53 weeks.

```js
function getWeekNumber(d) {
  d = new Date(+d);
  d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
  var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7)
  return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
}

function weeksInYear(year) {
  var d = new Date(year, 11, 31);
  var week = getWeekNumber(d)[1];
  return week == 1 ? 52 : week;
}

[2015, 2016, 2029, new Date().getFullYear()].forEach(year =>
  console.log(`${year} has ${weeksInYear(year)} weeks`)
);
```

Comment: Simpler than the do-loop would be to simply subtract 7.

Comment: @ScottSauyet—simpler yet is if 31 Dec is in week 1, the year has 52 weeks, otherwise 53. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Use isoWeek on the last day of the year to get the number of weeks e.g. :

```
function weeksInYear(year) {
   return Math.max(
            moment(new Date(year, 11, 31)).isoWeek()
          , moment(new Date(year, 11, 31-7)).isoWeek()
   );
}
```

Comment: What happens when 31 December is in week 1 of the following year?

Comment: The 28 Dec is always in the last week of a year, so you can simply get the ISO week of that date.

Answer (score 11):

[Feb. 4th 2014](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1462) the weeksInYear & isoWeeksInYear functions were added to moment.js

So today you can just use `moment().isoWeeksInYear()`or `moment().weeksInYear()`

For more into see the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weeks-in-year/)

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would post a much simpler version that I derived from the wikipedia article.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

The statement in the article is:

> "The number of weeks in a given year is equal to the corresponding
> week number of 28 December, because it is the only date that is always
> in the last week of the year since it is a week before 4 January which
> is always in the first week of the following year.
>
> Using only the ordinal year number y, the number of weeks in that year
> can be determined from a function, that
> returns the day of the week of 31 December"

Therefore `getWeekFor(new Date(2022, 11, 28)` replacing the year with any year you want will always give you the number of weeks for that year.

```js
// modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php 
const getWeekFor = (date) => {
    const d = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()));
    const dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
    const utc = new Date(d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum));
    const yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(utc.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1)).getTime();
    return Math.ceil(((d.getTime() - yearStart) / 86400000 + 1) / 7);
};

const weeks = getWeekFor(new Date(2020, 11, 28)) // 53.
console.log(weeks);
```

Answer (score -1):

Get all weeks and periods of that week for a year, for whom it may interest

```js
function getWeekPeriodsInYear(year) {
  weeks = [];

  // Get the first and last day of the year
  currentDay = moment([year, 1]).startOf('year');
  dayOfWeek = moment(currentDay).day();
  lastDay = moment([year, 1]).endOf('year');
  weeksInYear = moment(`${year}-01-01`).isoWeeksInYear();
  daysToAdd = 7 - dayOfWeek;

  for (let weekNumber = 1; weekNumber < weeksInYear + 1; weekNumber++) {
    let endOfWeek = moment(currentDay).add(daysToAdd, 'days');
    if (moment(endOfWeek).year() !== year) {
        endOfWeek = lastDay;
    }
    weeks.push({ weekNumber, start: currentDay.toDate(), end: endOfWeek.toDate() });
    currentDay = endOfWeek.add(1, 'day');
    daysToAdd = 6;
}
return weeks;
}

getWeekPeriodsInYear(new Date().getFullYear()).forEach(period =>
  document.write(`Week ${period.weekNumber} from ${moment(period.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')} up to and including ${moment(period.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}<br/>`)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```