# Is there a way to count number of ISO weeks in a given year using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to determine how many ISO weeks a year has.

My attempt looks like this

```
moment.tz(2019, "YYYY", "UTC").endOf("year").isoWeek()
```

But that doesn't do the job. 31st of December is ISO week 1 in some cases.

Ofc, there are probably some ugly ways to get the result, but i would like a clean code.

Comment: Why do you need to do that in UTC or ISO? Won't the weeks in a year be same irrespective of the timezone and date-time format?

Comment: A year has [52 weeks](https://crm.org/articles/how-many-weeks-in-a-year)...?! Give or take a day in a common year or two in a leap year, but isn't the answer always 52?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Get weeks in year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18478741/4131048)

Comment: @Shahzad No, ISO weeks are different. 

"ISO week year numbering therefore slightly deviates from the Gregorian for some days close to 1 January"

  - Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @JeremyThille Unfortunately, that's not the case for ISO weeks. A year can have 52 or 53 of them.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thank you! It seems to work. I didn't find this post before :/ I thought there would be a nice way in the moment library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like moment.js provides an interface for this.

This seems to be the solution (pure JS)
[Get weeks in year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478741/get-weeks-in-year)