# Create URL based on Year and week number like "2013-W32.html"

Tags: javascript, redirect, week-number

i would like to create a url based on the year and the week number in order to redirect to a document which the name changes every week :
the document is stored at this place : server.com/kw38_2013.pdf   (which kw38 mean week 38)

Does someone know a javascript for that ?

Regards

Emmanuel

Comment: Getting the year is easy with the date object http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp How do you handle the week numbers though? based ont he firts mondya of the year I assume and counted from there?

Answer (score 1):

It will be very easy to get year from a given date object in javascript. See [Date Object Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Whereas, Getting the week number from the given date will be tricky. Here is a similar question to get the week number from given date. See [Get week of year in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php) to get the week number.
You get the year by creating a Date object : `new Date().getFullYear()`