# Extjs getWeekOfYear returned wrong week number

Tags: javascript, extjs3

Is there any proper solution/patch to get week numbers correctly in extjs?

```
new Date('1 jan 2009').getWeekOfYear(); // will returned : 1
```

but

```
new Date('1 jan 2010').getWeekOfYear(); // will returned : 53
```

Comment: Looks like the returned week numbers are correct, at least according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: ok.
got the point.
but is there any logic to decide the week number at the starting of year.

Comment: note that 1 jan 2010 is the same week as the last week of 2009. Why do you need to alter this logic? It depends from `locale` in most languages - not sure about javascript

Comment: @bhavin There's [a formula](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6117889/1169519)..., or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation). Anyway you'd need some info of the previous year too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i got the complete idea, i was absolutely unaware of "first week" and "last week" funda.
Thanks guys for your kind support.