# Count Of JSON data as Daily, Weekly, Monthly in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have JSON Data which consist of Array of Data and  I wanted to find the count tags based on this day, this week this month data

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xznB7Wy5evolNIB6QsXT)

In the JSON Data I am getting the date Format as

```
2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000
```

Comment: what is your mean about _this day, this week, this month_?

Comment: I meant count of events which for today, which for this week, which is for this month like this..

Because here i just posted very small json data for reference but i have very huge JSON which will be containing the whole year data so

Comment: i think this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631750/8303694

Answer (score 1):

Maybe help you. You should get day and week and month of base date as you see. then loop through data and get issue date (`"created": "2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000"`) and create new date. so check it with base day,week, month of base date and go on.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "$window",
  function($scope, $http, $filter, $window) {
    $scope.data = {
      "expand": "schema,names",
      "startAt": 0,
      "maxResults": 50,
      "total": 257,
      "issues": [{
          "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
          "id": "1578077",
          "fields": {
            "created": "2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000",
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "status": {
              "name": "IN PROGRESS",
              "id": "10548"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
          "id": "1562078",
          "fields": {
            "created": "2017-07-27T03:42:24.000+0000",
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "status": {
              "name": "To Do",
              "id": "10548"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
          "id": "1562078",
          "fields": {
            "created": "2017-08-20T03:42:24.000+0000",
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "status": {
              "name": "To Do",
              "id": "10549"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
          "fields": {
            "created": "2017-08-11T13:03:52.000+0000",
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "status": {
              "name": "IN PROGRESS",
              "id": "3"
            }
          },
          "id": "1579217"
        }
      ]
    }
    var d = new Date("2017-08-10T13:14:53.000+0000");
    var day = d.getDay();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    $scope.dayCount = 0;
    $scope.monthEventCount = 0
    
    $scope.today = new Date();
    //var week = 
    $scope.findTheValue = function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.data.issues, function(issue) {
        var issueDate = new Date(issue.fields.created);
        if (issueDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == $scope.today.setHours(0,0,0,0))
          $scope.dayCount = $scope.dayCount + 1;
        if (issueDate.getMonth() == month)
          $scope.monthEventCount = $scope.monthEventCount + 1;
      })
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <button type="button" ng-click="findTheValue();">Submit</button>
    <div>{{dayCount}}</div>
    <div>{{monthEventCount}}</div>
    {{date}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I update answer for count month event. see update answer.

Comment: But Hadi I see dayCount is showing as 2 instead of 1 as we have only event with today date `"2017-08-20T03:42:24.000+0000",`

Comment: I think your mean about this day is day of base day not today date. see updated answer.