# jQuery date picker How to enable even week sundays only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this code i can enable only sundays. but how to disable sundays, if it is even week of the year.

```
function settings(date) {
    if (date.getDay() == 0) {
        return [true, "", "Works"];
    } else {
        return [false, "", ""];
    }
}

$i("#searchsectionbarids").datepicker({
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "DD",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: settings
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to get the week number of the year:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
    var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate());
    var dayOfYear = ((today - firstDay + 1) / 86400000);
    return Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)
};
```

and then

```
function settings(date) {
    if (date.getDay() == 0 && date.getWeek() % 2 == 1) {
        return [true, "", "Works"];
    } else {
        return [false, "", ""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must check the week is even or not 
You can reference at 
[Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Then you use your logic to setting your calendar

Good luck