# jQuery I would like to change the class of a div if that div's id is less than a var

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the class of a div if that div's id is less than the value of my var. This is my first time asking a question and my first time using jQuery so I sure this is embarrassingly easy, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
$(function(){
var today = new Date(); 
var weekno = today.getWeek()-1;
$("div[id$<weekno]").addClass("hidden");
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `ID`s with **numbers**, but I can write up a reasonable fiddle for you.

Comment: I added an answer that fits your question perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an example to of how do exactly as described: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/yJ4cu/2/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1">Hello world</div>
<div id="2">Hello world2</div>
<div id="15">Hello world2</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.foo {
    font-size:100px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
        if($(this).attr('id') < 10){
            $(this).addClass('foo');
        }
    });
});
```

#### So, what we're doing here with the `JS`:

```
$( "div" ).each(function( index ) { // Find every div
    if($(this).attr('id') < 10){    // if it has an ID of under x
        $(this).addClass('foo');    // add the class
    }
});
```

Comment: :-) I'm getting better and better at this every day. Thanks for the accepted answer!

Comment: Integer IDs for elements are not valid, you should consider changing them to start with a letter.

Comment: @tpbowden FYI From HTML5 numbered `ID` are *totally valid*

Comment: Do you have a resource we can look at to prove or learn that?

Comment: He's right, just looked it up and its explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Thanks, I didn't know that either.

Comment: BTW, thanks @boaz for formatting my enormous headings :-) I have a bad habit of that.

Answer (score 0):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ALAkizi/2/edit)***

```
$(function(){

    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var FY = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - FY) / 86400000) + FY.getDay()+1) / 7);
    };

    var weekno = new Date().getWeek();

  //alert(weekno);
    $("div").each(function(){
       var weekNum = this.id.match(/\d+/);
       if(weekNum  && weekNum < weekno){
           $(this).addClass("hidden");
       }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JavaScript has a method for getting the week number, so your first problem would be to find a way of calculating it. I would start by having a look at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Following that, you should look into HTML id values. Just using an integer is not valid, so you should figure out a way of incorporating the number somewhere after a string.

Your next place to look would be at CSS selectors. Conditionals for a less than in a selector is not valid, so you would probably have to iterate through each one (check out jQuery each) [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

I came up with a quick soluiton to your problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/vpgNL/

HTML:

```
<div class="week" id="week_2">Week 2</div>
<div class="week" id="week_5">Week 5</div>
<div class="week" id="week_11">Week 11</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var today = new Date(); 
    var weekno = 10;
    $(".week").each(function() {
        n = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        if(n < weekno) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that part of his code is working... the date. He just didn't include it because it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score -1):

First, Date object has no getWeek() method, Second, Do you want to use id attribute selector? You can try this:

> $("div[id$" + weekno + "]").addClass("hidden");

or you can [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)