# Use the Spreadsheet standard functions in Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I'm scripting and want to use a standard function e.g. `WEEKNUM`, is this possible directly or do I have to trigger the Formula into another field via `setFormula(formula)` and afterwards read the content from the related cell?

Answer (score 2):

The approach you describe is indeed possible but not efficient at all because it needs multiple calls to spreadsheet read / write which are relatively slow...

Using Native spreadsheet functions in JavaScript (Google-Apps-Script) is otherwise **not possible**.

Try to find an equivalent in JavaScript instead.

If you don't know how to get some result in JS, a search on Google will in most case bring an answer.

For your example of WEEKNUM, [a search](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find%20week%20number%20in%20javascript)  would return [this result for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)