# Javascript get week, wrong week number

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, dayofweek, week-number

got this get week script

```
    var d = new Date("2015-10-19T18:29:27.359Z");
    d.setHours(0,0,0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+4-(d.getDay()||7));
   var week = Math.ceil((((d-new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1))/8.64e7))/7);
console.log(week);
```

should return 43 (week number of 19/10)
but it returns 42

```
var d = new Date("2015-10-26T18:29:27.359Z");
```

returns week 44 as it should

looks likes it jumps over week 43?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Comment: When you say *"got this week script"*, does that mean you wrote it? Or does it mean you found it somewhere on the internet and now want us to debug it for you?

Comment: This script is not reliable because it doesn't take into account TimeZones and changes in DST.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You will see it says week is zero-based

Comment: thats the reason you get 42 instead of 43

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating it manually: use week input

```js
var elm = document.createElement('input')
elm.type = 'week'
elm.valueAsDate = new Date('2015-10-19T18:29:27.359Z')
var week = elm.value.slice(6)

console.log(week)
```

Comment: What if one has to do this in nodejs and not in the browser?

Comment: BTW You noticed, this question is more than 6 years old?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which will return week number from a given date in Typescript:

```js
/** return week number from given date */
export const getWeek = (refDate?:Date|number|string) => {
    const d = new Date(refDate !== undefined ? refDate : Date.now())
    const day = (d.getDay() + 6) % 7
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - day + 3)
    const firstThursday = d.getTime()
    d.setMonth(0, 1);
    if (d.getDay() !== 4) {
        d.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - d.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
    }
    return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - d.getTime()) / 604800000);
}
```

it should return correct value for the op sample:

```js
console.log(getWeek("2015-10-19T18:29:27.359Z")) // 43
console.log('Today's week number', getWeek())
```