# How do I convert the value of an "input type week" into date or numeric

Tags: java, angular, html

I have an element in html5:

```
<input class="form-control" #semana="ngModel" name="semana" [(ngModel)]="detalle.semana" type="week">
```

The value I get is a string "2018-W23" for example.
What I want is to get the value in date or number entered to perform operations on it (add or subtract days) and save it in my database.

I am working with Angular 5, JAVA spring and MySQL

Comment: Does "2018-W23" stand for 23th week of the year 2018?

Comment: yes, the theme is to be able to manipulate that value, but it takes it as a string and I want to convert it to date or number

Comment: I upload the inverse process, go from date to week that can also be of great help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474506/angular-2-date-pipe-weeknumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a conversion function to get a Date object from your week input.

See this discussion : [javascript calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number)

It appears there is no standard JS function to do that, so you have to implement your own function (again, see discussion - link above) to parse the week input into a Date object.

Then with your Date object it will be convenient to do operations (add days etc) and save it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking how to do it in Javascript, you can easily do so using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

```js
moment( document.querySelector("#weekInput").value ).format("yyyy/MMMM/DD")
```