# How to get week number in JS

Tags: javascript

We need to get week number OF MONTH in JS, for make a alert in HTML, any idea?
We try using getday js function and yes, it work, but just show the number day of generic week.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: Try something, then show what you have tried in your question, along with errors, actual/expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

call function with : (new Date()).getWeek()

```js
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var date = new Date(this.getTime());
   date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);

  var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
  return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000
                        - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
}

Date.prototype.getWeekYear = function() {
  var date = new Date(this.getTime());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
  return date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: A lot of magic numbers in your code

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I `new Date(2000, 5, 26).getWeek()` returns 26, and according to http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2000, April, 26 2000 should be week 17

Comment: If you want to create a Date object using new Date (2000, 5, 26), start of the month index = 0 (5 = June), so you have to use new Date (2000, 4, 26).
You can use the following syntax new Date ('5/26/2016')

Comment: Oops, sorry... off by two, I added instead of subtracting