# How to Check Given Date is This week or Last Week in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to check the given date is **'Today', 'Yesterday', 'This Week', 'Last Week', 'This Month', 'Last Month', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', .... '2019', '2018',** etc.... in JavaScript.

and I am using Moment js for showing Datetime

```
moment.tz(message.receivedDateTime, 'America/Denver').format("hh:mm A")
```

We have an array of the message with content and date of that messages has received, so we need to Check Date and showing list of messages like the following format in JavaScript.

```
Today
    Message 1 
    Message 2
Yesterday
    Message 3
    Message 4
This Week
    Message 5
Last Week
    Message 6
    Message 7
```

etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if date is in this week in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787908/how-to-check-if-date-is-in-this-week-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but if you don't have a way this could be helpful to your own. You can support on [`calendar()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) which says:

> Calendar time displays time relative to a given referenceDay (defaults to the start of today). [...] **Note**: From version 2.25.0 you can only pass a formats argument, it could be an object of strings and functions.

The defaults for this are:

```js
moment().calendar({
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

> `sameElse` is used as the format when the moment is more than a week away from the referenceDay.

And [`difference()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get the difference in milliseconds, or in another unit of measurement.

So for cases less than a week (or 7 days) you can use `lastWeek` and for those cases more than a week use `sameElse`, something like this:

```js
function calendarDate(date) {
  return moment(date).calendar({
    sameElse: function (now) {
      const from = moment(this);
      now = moment(now);
      const dayDiff = now.diff(from, 'days');
      if (dayDiff >= 7 && dayDiff <= 14) {
        return '[Last week]';
      } else {
        const monthDiff = now.diff(from, 'months', true);
        if (monthDiff === 0) {
          return '[This month]';
        }
        if (monthDiff > 0 && monthDiff <= 1) {
          return '[Last Month]';
        }
        if (monthDiff > 1) {
          if (Number(from.format('YYYY')) - Number(now.format('YYYY')) < 0) {
            return `[${from.format('YYYY')}]`;
          }
          return `[${from.format('MMMM')}]`;
        }
      }
      return '[More than a week]';
    },
  });
}

console.log(calendarDate('2020-11-01'));
console.log(calendarDate('2020-10-23'));
console.log(calendarDate('2020-09-30'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Also you can return you message directly from the function instead of the "time ago" string.

Remember that this is just an example and you can adjust the ranges according to your needs.