# Show yyyyww (yearweek) in Google Scripts / Javascript (Sunday-Monday)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm really struggling to do a clean, efficient way of showing yearweek for Sunday to Monday

e.g.:
201624
201625
201626
201627
201628

Is there an efficient way to do so in Google Scripts or Javascript without using a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! :

var yearMonth = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyyww")).toFixed(0);

It was provided by user: **Balu Ertl** at [Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Moment.js. Documentation for the use can be found here for the format you are looking for http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/.

To have it work with google script you will need to first add it to the libraries using `MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48`, then you need to load it in using something like `var moment = Moment.load()`.

From here you can get the month and year already formatted into your requested format.

```js
var date = getDate();

var wwyy = moment(date).format('wo, YY');
```

My appologies, my format wasn't exactly as you wanted it to be. To answer in the format you are looking for:

```js
var date = new Date();

var yyyyww = moment(date).format('YYYY ww');
```