# Week number counter with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, date, time

I'm currently trying to make a date / week counter, where you can increase or decrease the week number alongside the date of the week's first and last day. This is what I've got so far thanks to **@ishegg**

```html
<script>
   
    var curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    curr.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    function week() {
        curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

        // First day of the week
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();

        // Last day of the week
        var last = first + 6;

        var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));

        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = startDate;
        document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = endDate;

        // Week number
        Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
            var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
            var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
            d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
            var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
            return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
        };
        document.getElementById("week").innerHTML = ("Week " + curr.getWeekNumber());
    }

    function startOfWeek(date) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        return date;
    }

    function endOfWeek(date) {
        date = startOfWeek(date);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
        return date; 
    }

    function weekPlus() {
    
        var startDate = new Date(startOfWeek(curr));
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);
        var endDate = endOfWeek(curr);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7);
        curr = startDate;

        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = startDate;
        document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = endDate;

        // Week number
        Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
            var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
            var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
            d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
            var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
            return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7 + 1);
        };
        document.getElementById("week").innerHTML = ("Week " + curr.getWeekNumber());
    }

    function weekMinus() {

        var startDate = new Date(startOfWeek(curr));
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
        var endDate = endOfWeek(curr);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 7);
        curr = startDate;

        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = startDate;
        document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = endDate;

        // Week number
        Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
            var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
            var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
            d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
            var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
            return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7 - 1);
        };
        document.getElementById("week").innerHTML = ("Week " + curr.getWeekNumber());
    }    
</script>


<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="end">end</div>
<div id="week">week</div>
<button onclick="week()">current</button>
<button onclick="weekPlus()">add</button>
<button onclick="weekMinus()">substract</button>
```

So after you press the *current* -button, you'll get the last and first day of the week including the week number.

You can add or substract by 1 week with each button press.

**Problems with the code:**

- <s>After adding or substracting the weeks -> pressing the *current* -button to reset the weeks to the current date, adding or substracting doesn't start from the current week, but from before you press the *current* button.</s>
- After pressing  the *add* -button couple of times and then pressing *substract*, the week number instantly goes down by 3, instead of 1. (Same thing reversed, going up by 3, instead of 1)
- Whenever the year changes, sometimes the week jumps straight to week 2.

Any idea's how to solve these problems with the code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's because you're using a *local variable* `curr` within your week function, and you probably meant to update the *global variable* curr instead.  Solution - within week() don't use `var` in front of `curr`

Comment: @James Thank you, got it fixed. Any idea's about why the week number jumps by 3 instead of 1 after adding couple of times and then substracting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Date#set****` functions mutate the argument. This affects also `curr` at times you don't really want that to happen.

Solve this by making sure that the functions `startOfWeek` and `endOfWeek` do not modify their arguments, but return new Date instances. And then stick to calling those functions where possible, avoiding code duplication. There are only a few places where `curr` should be modified, and that is in the `week` (I renamed it to `weekReset`) and the `weekPlus` function (and `weekMin`, but see next point).

I would remove `weekMin`, as it has the same logic as `weekPlus`. You can settle the difference by providing `weekPlus` a parameter.

Don't redefine `Date.prototype.getWeekNumber` over and over again: just do this once.

Finally, split the rendering logic from the date calculations, again to avoid code duplication. I would create a separate `display` function for generating the output. Note that you don't need `document.getElementById` since current browsers create global variables for elements that have an `id`. This was also the reason I renamed the `week` function so it would not coincide with the variable for the element with that `id`.

Here is the revised code:

```js
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
    var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
    return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
};

var curr;
weekReset();

function display() {
    start.textContent = curr;
    end.textContent = endOfWeek(curr);
    week.textContent = ("Week " + curr.getWeekNumber());
}

function weekReset() {
    curr = startOfWeek(new Date());
    display();
}

function startOfWeek(date) {
    var start = new Date(date);
    start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay());
    return start;
}

function endOfWeek(date) {
    date = startOfWeek(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
    return date; 
}

function weekPlus(weeks) {
    curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 7 * weeks);
    display();
}
```

```html
<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="end">end</div>
<div id="week">week</div>
<button onclick="weekReset()">current</button>
<button onclick="weekPlus(1)">add</button>
<button onclick="weekPlus(-1)">substract</button>
```

Comment: Thank you works great. If the `weekReset()` , `weekPlus()` and `weekMinus()` functions we're on different pages, do I need to call `Date.prototype.getWeekNumber` on each of the pages or can I just call it inside the `week()` function page and use it on the other pages?

Comment: That's because I gather alot more different data other than week number and dates from these functions, so they have to be on different pages.

Comment: You need to *define* Date.prototype.getWeekNumber` on each page that references it. It is no different as other functions: you need to define them where you use them.

Comment: But I would put all the functions (including the `Date.prototype.getWeekNumer` function ) in a `.js` file, and include that script with a `script` tag in all the pages that need (some of) it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Any idea how I could change the `getWeekNumber` -function to get the week number for my time zone? It says Week 34, but it should be week 35.

Comment: There are different systems of week numbering. The code you have used calculates the [ISO week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php), but maybe you have another system in mind. If you can't find the answer by a search, then I would suggest asking a new question just about that, explaining the logic with which you determine which week should get number 1, for all 7 possible ways a year can start.