# Calculating week number with typescript - right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been looking around allot for code to use in my program that will calculate the week number (according to [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standards) in my Angular app using typescript. It is very hard to find a piece of code just in JavaScript, but I think I may have found something- problem is I get an error: *The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.*

I have NO idea what this means. 
Here is a service that I have tried to write to use the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WeekNumberService {

  constructor() { }

 ISO8601_week_no(dt)  {
  var tdt = new Date(dt.valueOf());
  var dayn = (dt.getDay() + 6) % 7;
  tdt.setDate(tdt.getDate() - dayn + 3);
  var firstThursday = tdt.valueOf();
  tdt.setMonth(0, 1);
  if (tdt.getDay() !== 4) 
    {
   tdt.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - tdt.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
     }
  return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - tdt) / 604800000);
  }

}
```

PS: I am in the end only looking for the week number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tdt` is a `Date` and `firstThursday` is infered as a `number` because `tdt.valueOf()` returns a number representing the stored time value in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

You cannot use an arithmetic operations between these two variables :

```
firstThursday - tdt.
```

Anyway, your actual code is not designed to return a representation of an *ISO_8601 week date* as you specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).
You return a `Date` while you should return a `String`.
For example, this input `Date` `Monday 29 December 2008` should return this `String` : `"2009-W01-1"`.

Getting the year and the day number of the week is straight as Date provides methods for :

```
var dayNumber = date.getDay() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

About the week number of the year, you have to implement this.
I invite you to rely on the code in the accepted answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php).

Then, just concatenate the three values :

```
String isoWeek = year + "-W-" + weekNumber + "-" + dayNumber;
```

Comment: I will watch your interventions the next days :) Oh... Relativise : Your Mac Pro Book  will have a little delay but enjoy, as Mac, you are today a legend :)

Comment: I have decided to (just for now) remove this as the right answer, due to the fact the post you have referred to uses the following line: var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7); Here "d" is also a date, yet it is used in an arithmetic operation, which no surprise if I use that code: gives me the exact same error... any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I marked it correct again because I see that you did give the right answer, without actually specifically pointing it out. Maybe you can just change your answer for future reference to say that all I need to do was to use "tdt.valueOf()" in the "return" line, instead of just tdt. Thanks again.