# How to highlight current week in air date picker calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/

I am using air date picker calendar. How can i highlight the current week in the calendar. See my fiddle location.

http://jsfiddle.net/oua394nt/

```
<input type="text"
    data-range="true"
    data-multiple-dates-separator=" - "
    data-language="en" id="my-element"
    class="datepicker-here"/>
```

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/superigno/ev9f5/

Comment: please check my fiddle. you are using jquery ui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since AFAICS *Air Datepicker* does not adds week number into the cells `data-`, you could use a script to **get the week number** (edited [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117889/383904)):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/uzf4c50d/3/)**

- Get and store the current week number.
- Use the [Air Datepicker `onRenderCell()`](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-45) method and add a class to the cells whose date's week number equals the current week number:

CSS:

```
.-current-week- {
  background: red;
}
```

JS:

```
function getWeek(d) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117889/383904
  d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay()||7));
  var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
  var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
  return {year:d.getUTCFullYear(), number: weekNo};
}

var currentWeekNumber = getWeek(new Date()).number;

$('#my-element').datepicker({
  onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
    if (cellType === 'day' && getWeek(date).number === currentWeekNumber) {
      return {
        classes: '-current-week-',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with Jquery but [Here is an example of highlight with Angular and Dayjs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bljctw)
(hard to find examples of combination with Angular/Air Datepicker) !

```
import isSameOrBefore from 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore';
...

dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(isSameOrAfter);
dayjs.extend(isSameOrBefore);

new AirDatepicker('#airPicker', {
  onRenderCell({ date, cellType }) {
    let dateUtc = dayjs(date).utc();
    let utcWeekStart = dayjs().utc().startOf('week');
    let utcWeekEnd = dayjs().utc().endOf('week');

    if (
      dateUtc.isSameOrAfter(utcWeekStart) &&
      dateUtc.isSameOrBefore(utcWeekEnd)
    ) {
      return {
        classes: '-current-week-',
      };
    }
  },
}
```

CSS

```
.-current-week- {
  background: rgba(138, 79, 30, 0.1);
}
```