# Get week number of the month from date (weeks starting on Mondays)

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601, week-number

I have to find week number of the month from given date using JavaScript. Week start is Monday.

I have tried the code below but not getting accurate result.

```js
function getWeekNumber(date) {
  var monthStartDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);
  monthStartDate = new Date(monthStartDate);
  var day = monthStartDate.getDay();
  date = new Date(date);
  var date = date.getDate();

  let weekNumber = Math.ceil((date + (day)) / 7);
  return (weekNumber == 0) ? 1 : weekNumber;
}

var week = getWeekNumber('2020-04-04');
console.log(week);
```

Comment: How is it different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/6117814/4636715

Comment: @vahdet I want week number of month not year.

Comment: What is "week number of month" for? You mean week 1-4 depending on where the Thursday is? So we are in week 2 of March today the 14th?

Comment: @mplungjan e.g date is 2020-04-05 then week number should be 1.

Comment: Why? the Monday of that week is in the previous month https://www.acu.ac.uk/calendar/month?filters%5Bdate%5D=2020-04-05&show_sources%5Bblue%5D=0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: @epascarello I already used that as a dupe but it is not

Comment: If any of the answers answered your question, please mark it as 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
function getWeek(date) {
  let monthStart = new Date(date);
  monthStart.setDate(0);
  let offset = (monthStart.getDay() + 1) % 7 - 1; // -1 is for a week starting on Monday
  return Math.ceil((date.getDate() + offset) / 7);
}
getWeek(new Date(2019, 2, 14))
```

Comment: Just remember to use a valid date as an argument. If you send something like 02/31/2020, the result will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the week number of the month for weeks starting on Monday (in line with the [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) system) by rolling the input date back to the previous Monday and then dividing the Monday date by 7 and rounding up to determine which week of the month the date falls in.

This approach will properly handle dates at the beginning of a month which actually fall in the last week of the previous month. For instance, 2020-04-04 is a Saturday in the week starting on 2020-03-30 (Monday), so it should return week 5 since it is part of the 5th week of March (and not part of the 1st week of April which starts on 2020-04-06, the first Monday in April).

For example (the `split` bit at the beginning is just to parse the date string rather than relying on `new Date()` to parse the string since that is not recommended due to browser inconsistencies):

```js
const monthWeek = (s) => {
  const [y, m, d] = s.split('-'); // parse date string
  const date = new Date(y, m - 1, d); // create date object
  date.setDate(d - ((date.getDay() + 6) % 7)); // adjust date to previous Monday
  return Math.ceil(date.getDate() / 7); // return week number of the month
};

console.log(monthWeek('2020-04-04'));
// 5
console.log(monthWeek('2020-04-07'));
// 1
```