# How to convert a unix epoch to [year, month, day] via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small need where i want to convert a timestamp stored in a variable say `doc.creation_time` to a format `[year,month,day]`

example:

`doc.creation_time` = `1537492812` 
this should be converted to `[2018,38,Fri]`

Can someone help

Comment: `Fri` is not defined?

Comment: `new Date(doc.creation_time * 1000)` (it takes milliseconds so we multiply it by 1000) to make a Date object, then you can get all kinds of stuff out of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Month 38???????

Comment: Do you want ISO-week or not? Do your weeks start with Sunday or Monday?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var creation_time = 1537492812;
var date = new Date(creation_time * 1000);
var weekday = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

// UTC
console.log(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth() + 1, weekday[date.getUTCDay()]);

// Local
console.log(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, weekday[date.getDay()]);
```

Comment: @NishantSingh use an additional function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs for your requirement

```
var creation_time = 1537492812;
//var date = moment.unix(creation_time).format('YYYY,MM,ddd');
var date = moment.unix(creation_time).format('YYYY,w,ddd');
var result = date.split(',');
console.log(result);
```

```js
var creation_time = 1537492812;
//var date = moment.unix(creation_time).format('YYYY,MM,w, ddd');
var date = moment.unix(creation_time).format('YYYY,w,ddd');
var result = date.split(',');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I updated the week in answer, if you dont want the month var date = moment.unix(creation_time).format('YYYY,w, ddd');