# Can I add custom methods to Google Apps Script classes?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, prototype

I want to invoke custom methods on Google Apps Script classes such as *Spreadsheet*, *Sheet*, and *DriveApp*.
In https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117889, a minimal prototyping solution is used to add a method to the Javascript Date() class to get the week number. Is it possible to apply the same strategy to Google Apps Script classes?

As an example, I want to create a custom method for the Spreadsheet class that allows the spreadsheet to be moved to a particular folder in my google drive given the ID of that folder. Here is what I've tried:

```
Spreadsheet.prototype.moveToFolder = function(folderID) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(this.getId());
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  file.moveTo(destination);
}
```

However, I get the error message "ReferenceError: Spreadsheet is not defined".
Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to add custom methods.  But `Spreadsheet` class is not directly accessible. So, it is needed to first get a instance of Spreadsheet class using any of methods available:

```
const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

Then use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) on the `Spreadsheet` instance to get it's prototype.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Spreadsheet).myMethod = function (){
  console.info("myMethod was called!")
  return true;
}
```

Any property defined on the prototype will then propogate through all Spreadsheet instances.

#### Update:

The prototype object returned by `Object.getPrototypeOf(Spreadsheet)` is `Object`. This can also be confirmed by logging `Spreadsheet.constructor.name`. **This means that there is no special Spreadsheet prototype or constructor used to create the Spreadsheet instance**. Therefore, Although you can add custom methods, They're added to all objects say, `Range`, `DriveApp`  and any object created with `var obj = {}` or `Object.create("Any object except null")`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Spreadsheet doesn't have a unique prototype but actually uses that of `Object`, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538462/1329498) by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster), you can simply add your method to the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) prototype.

```
Object.prototype.moveToFolder = function(folderID) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(this.getId());
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  file.moveTo(destination);
}
```

Since this method will apply to all objects, you should ask yourself if it's really worth doing. See "[Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)"

Instead of modifying the native object, you could create a new class that "inherits" the native methods while also giving you the ability to override and add new methods.

```
function main() {
  const ss = new Spreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
  console.log(ss._native.getName()); // MySpreadsheet
  console.log(ss.getName()); // The name is MySpreadsheet
  
  ss.moveToFolder(FOLDER_ID);
}

class Spreadsheet {
  constructor(native) {
    this._native = native;
    
    // Copy native's methods to this
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this._native).forEach(property => {
      this[property] = this._native[property];
    });
    
    // Override native methods
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      'getName': {
        value: function() {
          return `The name is ${this._native.getName()}`;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  moveToFolder(folderId) {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(this.getId());
    const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    file.moveTo(destination);
  }
}
```