# Cannot override google app script's console.log()

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, console.log

I have a large google app script writing lots of log line to the log explorer. I want to be able to disable or enable logging if needed.

Here's a code that seems to work as expected on a browser.
Here `allowlog` is set in code, but it will retrieved from external source. This is not important for the purpose of this post.

The self extracting function overrides `console.log` and blocks logging if needed.

```
let allowLog = false; 

function func1(){
  console.log("func1 log msg");
}

(function(){
  //test log 1
  console.log("self extracting");

  //keep ref to global console.log
  const _consolelog = console.log;

  //test log 2 - verify it works
  _consolelog("self extracting2");


//override global console.log
  console.log = function(val){
    if (allowLog){
      _consolelog(val);
      _consolelog("allowing");
    }else{
      _consolelog("log disabled");
    }

  }

})();
```

This code does not work on google app script, and logs keep on writing.

In app script I can see  `console.log("self extracting");` and  `_consolelog("self extracting2");` log messages when module is loaded. However when `func1` is called log is written even though `allowLog = false`.
`_consolelog("allowing");` nor `_consolelog("log disabled");` is NOT logged. the global console.log is not overridden.

Why is that, and how (if at all) it is possible to fix it?

The expected log for the above code is (`allowLog=false`):

- self extracting
- self extracting2
- log disabled

For the case where `allowLog=true`:

- self extracting
- self extracting2
- func1 log msg
- allowing

The first two lines **self extracting** and **self extracting2** should be printed only once, when the anonymous self invoking function is executed. The other should come from the internal function which overides the global one

Comment: When testing this code as-is, running `func`()` prints `self extracting`, `self extracting2` and `func1 log msg` as I would expect. What do you see that is different and why do you expect something different?  Also, you can't override Apps Script classes simply like that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538462/11551468) for more information

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou please see my update for your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is  because the `log` property of `console` is not `writable`. You can check that using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`. However, it is still [`configurable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). So, you can `delete` the `log` property and set a new value.

```
let allowLog = false; 
(function(){
  //test log 1
  console.log("self extracting");

  //keep ref to global console.log
  const _consolelog = console.log;

  //test log 2 - verify it works
  _consolelog("self extracting2");


//override global console.log
//console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(console));
/*{ toString: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  time: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  timeEnd: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  error: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: false,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  info: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: false,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  log: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: false,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true },
  warn: 
   { value: [Function],
     writable: false,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true } }*/
  delete console.log;
  console.log = function (val){
    if (allowLog){
      _consolelog(val);
      _consolelog("allowing");
    }else{
      _consolelog("log disabled");
    }
  }
})();

function func1(){
  console.log("func1 log msg");
}
```

Comment: perfect explanation and solution.

Comment: great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
Logger.log('Test1');  // it will print as usual

var _log = Logger.log
Logger.log = function(_){};

Logger.log('Test2'); // <-- it will not print since we disabled the 'log()' method

Logger.log = _log;   // restore the method 'log()' back
Logger.log('Test3'); // it will print again
```

Output:

```
Test1
Test3
```

[image]

Comment: Conceptually this is what I want. It seems to work with `Logger` but not with `console`. console class provides better interface (like severity , `console.log()` `console.error()` etc) allowing filtering log messages in the cloud log explorer. Is it possible with class `console` somehow?

Comment: Well. It looks like it's impossible. I can be wrong, though. Perhaps there might be the barbarian solution just to replace all `console.` with `if (allowLog) console.` (Don't forget to make a copy of the code :) )

Comment: you say barbarian - so I guess I have a cleaner solution. just replace all the very many `console.xxx()` calls to something like `_console.xxx()` where `_console` is a wrapper object. with the help of the _Visual Studio Code_ find and replace is it not that hard. Barbaric as I am, I'm actually not sure I understand your solution.. are you suggesting to enclose all `console` calls with an `if` statement ?

Comment: Yep. I meant `if (allowLog) console.log(...);`. Your solution is less barbarian. I think I'd go with it.

Comment: :) maybe I will. I'll wait to see whether someone else will provide a better solution

Comment: See _TheMaster_ solution. clear and beautiful

Comment: Beautiful as hell I'd say. )

Comment: very much indeed

Comment: This might not be the answer but still is commendable I say. +1