# Object Array with dates, tallied together for each month

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, datetime, object

**Overview**

1. I need to make a chart in my react project.
2. Using data from a json (Object Array).
   Example json:

```
[
{recruiter_id: 1, datetime_created: "1/01/2021", name: "Aaron"},
{recruiter_id: 2, datetime_created: "9/01/2021", name: "Bob"},
{recruiter_id: 1, datetime_created: "9/01/2021", name: "Aaron"},
{recruiter_id: 3, datetime_created: "20/01/2021", name: "Jane"}
]
```

3. Result object array structure required:

```
[
{name: name,
 recruiter_id: recruiter_id,
 week_qty: [0,2,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,...] },
...]

// week_qty will be an array of 52 to represent each week of the year. It will be a 0 if there was no dates for that week.
```

---

**Goal**

This is what the new object array should look like, if we used the example json.

```
[
{name: "Aaron", recruiter_id:1, week_qty: [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...]},
{name: "Bob", recruiter_id:2, week_qty: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...]},
{name: "Jane", recruiter_id:3, week_qty: [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...]}
]
```

---

**What I have**

I dont have any working code yet. I am currently working on object[0] to attempt to put the dates into the 52 array. And then after that I will then turn it into a loop to work on each object. Once I have it semi working, I will post it for example.

--- Edit ---

```
   var array = result
        var flags = [], output = [], l = array.length, i;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (flags[array[i].recruiter_id]) continue;
            flags[array[i].recruiter_id] = true;
            var temp = {}
            temp.Recruiter_id = array[i].recruiter_id
            temp.Name = array[i].name
            temp.QTY = []
            output.push(temp);
        }
        console.log("output : ", output)
```

This produces the new object array structure with the id and name filled out.

```
[
{name: name,
 recruiter_id: recruiter_id,
 week_qty: [] },
...]
```

It only has 1 object for each id

Now I need to work on getting the week numbers for the dates and put them into each of those objects.

---

**Question**

Any code suggestions on how to get this result?

---

**Side Note**

If your curious to know how I then plan on using the new object array to use with my chart.

1. I will let the user select the week. Lets say week 1.
2. I will then map through the object array and get the week_qty for index 1 and the name value of the object.
3. I will store that week_qty and the name in a new new object array.
4. That new new object array will then look like this

```
[{name: "Aaron",QTY: 2},{name: "Bob",QTY: 1,]
```

5. That will then be passed as the x and y value to the chart.

Comment: Are you using any library for dates like `moment.js` / `date-fns`/ `Luxon` etc ?

Comment: No, I use this to get a clean date from the original json from the db.

    object_array.map(data => {
        data.datetime_created = new Date(data[datetime_key]).toLocaleString().split(",")[0]
    })
    return object_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and increase the week counter after parsing each date and getting the week (*using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for that part here*)

But you can see [Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php) for more details on how to calculate it yourself

```js
const data = [
  {recruiter_id: 1, datetime_created: "1/01/2021", name: "Aaron"},
  {recruiter_id: 2, datetime_created: "9/01/2021", name: "Bob"},
  {recruiter_id: 1, datetime_created: "9/01/2021", name: "Aaron"},
  {recruiter_id: 3, datetime_created: "20/01/2021", name: "Jane"}
 ];

const weekly = data.reduce((acc, item, index, array) => {
  const {
    recruiter_id,
    datetime_created,
    name
  } = item;
  let existing = acc.find(({
    recruiter_id: id
  }) => id === recruiter_id);
  
  if (!existing) {
    existing = {recruiter_id, name, week_qty:Array(52).fill(0)};
    acc.push(existing);
  }
  
  const week = moment(datetime_created,'D/M/YYYY').week()-1;
  existing.week_qty[week]++;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(weekly))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```