# Get total elapsed business hours between two datetimes

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to calculate the amount of vacation hours taken between two datetimes.  Since this is a vacation (leave, PTO) application, it's important that I find the amount of elapsed vacation time taken between two datetimes.

Vacation time is measured by the number of hours taken off during the company business hours, which is between 9:00:00 and 18:00:00.

For example :

```
let start_at = '2021-12-27 14:00:00';
let end_at = '2021-12-28 14:00:00';
```

`start_at - end_at` results in 1 day.  24 hours.

The result I expect is **9** hours, not 1 day completely.

How can I count distinct intervals of business hours (e.g., 9 hour blocks) instead of the actual time range?

Comment: `start - end` is most likely not the elapsed time between two dates in a way you need the time, use `end - start` instead. If you need more accurate answer, pleas show your code.

Comment: yea i wrong  in typing its true ent_at - start_at , tnx

Comment: Why are you doing leave in a CMS? Leave is a payroll function. Calculating leave isn't trivial and usually depends on each day worked, with a nominal 8 hours per day. If a person works less hours in a day, they have to take leave to cover the shortfall, so they still get a full credit of leave which then has the shortfall deducted. All that is handled in conjunction with a timesheet system. If they work overtime, they either get extra pay or time in lieu (i.e. extra leave). There are also usually penalty rates for public holidays, weekends, early/late hours, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i write this method ( icluded datetime picker + convert date to Shamsi/Jalali  and other helpers method  for calculate vacation time

I use MdPersianDateTimePicker for datetime picker
https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker

All window.JSAPP.methods.* is my helpers function that i write for this method

```
 // Get from server ( user config Or settings ) (  this check from server )
                var work_group_start_time = window.work_group_start_time; // 09:00:00
                var work_group_end_time = window.work_group_end_time; // 18:00:00

                var work_group_thursday_start_time = window.work_group_thursday_start_time; // 09:00:00;
                var work_group_thursday_end_time = window.work_group_thursday_end_time; // 15:00:00

                var min_vacation_time_in_minute = window.min_vacation_time_in_minute; // 60
                var max_vacation_time_in_hour = window.max_vacation_time_in_hour; // 18

                var hollydays = window.hollydays; // ['2022-01-02']
                var v_off_days = window.v_off_days; // ['Friday']

                window.JSAPP.methods.disableFormOnSubmit('#vacation-create-form');

                var  submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_vacation');
                var time_input = $("#vacation_time");
                submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                submitButton.disabled = true;


                var disabledDays = window.JSAPP.methods.disabledDays(v_off_days);


// my datetime picker and its configurations configs ( start date picker )
                $('#start_date_text').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    targetTextSelector: '#start_date_text',
                    targetDateSelector: '#start_date_date',
                    textFormat:'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm',
                    dateFormat:'yyyy_MM_dd___HH__mm',
                    englishNumber: true,
                    inLine: false,
                    disableAfterToday: false,
                    //disableBeforeToday : true,
                    enableTimePicker: true,
                    fromDate: true,
                    disabledDays : disabledDays,
                    groupId: 'date_start_end-range',
                    disabledDates : window.JSAPP.methods.disabledDates(hollydays),
                });

// my datetime picker and its configurations configs ( end datetime picker )
                $('#end_date_text').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    targetTextSelector: '#end_date_text',
                    targetDateSelector: '#end_date_date',
                    textFormat:'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm',
                    dateFormat:'yyyy_MM_dd___HH__mm',
                    englishNumber: true,
                    inLine: false,
                    disableAfterToday: false,
                    enableTimePicker: true,
                    //disableBeforeToday : true,
                    toDate: true,
                    disabledDays : disabledDays,
                    groupId: 'date_start_end-range',
                    disabledDates : window.JSAPP.methods.disabledDates(hollydays),
                });


                // Calculate

                var in_day_work_time = (((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_end_time) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_start_time))/(1000*60))/60);

                var in_day_work_thursday_time = (((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_thursday_end_time) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_thursday_start_time))/(1000*60))/60);

                vacationCalculate();

                $("#start_date_date , #end_date_date").on('change keyup input focusout',function(){

                    vacationCalculate();

                });


                function vacationCalculate(){

                    time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                    time_input.removeClass('text-danger');
                    time_input.val('');
                    submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                    submitButton.disabled = true;

                    function is_off_day(dayName,date){

                        if((v_off_days != "undefined" && window.in_array(dayName,v_off_days)) || (hollydays != "undefined" && window.in_array(date,hollydays))){
                            return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }

                    $("#vacation_time_help").html('');

                    var vacationTime = 0;

                    let  start_at = $("#start_date_date").val();
                    let  end_at = $("#end_date_date").val();

                    if((start_at && start_at != null && start_at != '' && start_at.length == 19) && (end_at && end_at != null && end_at != '' && end_at.length == 19)){

                        start_at = start_at.replace(/___/g,' ').replace(/__/g,':').replace(/_/g,'-');
                        start_at = start_at+':00';

                        end_at = end_at.replace(/___/g,' ').replace(/__/g,':').replace(/_/g,'-');
                        end_at = end_at+':00';

                        let start_date = start_at.split(' ')[0];
                        let end_date = end_at.split(' ')[0];

                        let start_time = start_at.split(' ')[1];
                        let end_time = end_at.split(' ')[1];

                        var max_off_time = 0;

                        // tStart = window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(start_time,end_date.replace(/-/g,'/'));
                        // tStop = window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(end_time,end_date.replace(/-/g,'/'));

                        var temp_dayName = window.JSAPP.methods.dayName(start_date,'string');

                        if(temp_dayName === 'Thursday'){
                            work_group_start_time = work_group_thursday_start_time;
                            work_group_end_time = work_group_thursday_end_time;
                        }


                        if(end_at && start_at){

                            if(end_at > start_at){

                                if(start_at !== end_at){

                                    if(start_date === end_date){

                                        let dayName = window.JSAPP.methods.dayName(start_date,'string');

                                        if(!is_off_day(dayName,start_date)){

                                            let _work_group_end_time = work_group_end_time;

                                            if(dayName === 'Thursday'){
                                                _work_group_end_time = work_group_thursday_end_time;
                                            }

                                            if(start_time <= work_group_start_time ){
                                                start_time = work_group_start_time;
                                            }


                                            // if(end_time > _work_group_end_time || end_time < work_group_start_time ){
                                            //
                                            //     end_time = _work_group_end_time;
                                            //
                                            // }


                                            if(end_time > _work_group_end_time){

                                                end_time = _work_group_end_time;
                                            }



                                            console.log(start_date+' '+start_time+' --- '+start_date+' '+end_time+' ---- '+((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(end_time,start_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(start_time,start_date))/(1000*60)));

                                            max_off_time = ((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(end_time,start_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(start_time,start_date))/(1000*60));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    else{

                                        let start_at_timestamp = window.JSAPP.methods.stringToTimestamp(start_date+" "+"00:00:00");

                                        let end_at_timestamp = window.JSAPP.methods.stringToTimestamp(end_date+" "+"23:59:59");

                                        let vacation_diff = window.JSAPP.methods.diffInDay(start_at_timestamp,end_at_timestamp);


                                        var days = parseInt(vacation_diff.day-1);


                                        for(let i=0; i <= days; i++){


                                            let thisDate;
                                            let diffInM = 0;
                                            let dayName;

                                            thisDate = window.JSAPP.methods.addDays(window.JSAPP.methods.getSafeDate(start_date), i);
                                            dayName = window.JSAPP.methods.dayName(thisDate,'date');


                                            if(i === 0){
                                                if(!is_off_day(dayName,start_date)){


                                                    let _work_group_end_time = work_group_end_time;


                                                    if(dayName === 'Thursday'){
                                                        _work_group_end_time = work_group_thursday_end_time;
                                                    }

                                                    let _work_group_start_time = work_group_start_time;

                                                    // 17:45 <= 18:00:00 && 15:45 >= 9:00:00
                                                    if(start_time <= _work_group_end_time && start_time >=  work_group_start_time){
                                                        _work_group_start_time = start_time;
                                                    }

                                                    diffInM  = ((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_end_time,start_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_start_time,start_date))/(1000*60));

                                                    console.log(start_date+' '+_work_group_start_time+' --- '+start_date+' '+_work_group_end_time+' ---- '+((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_end_time,start_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_start_time,start_date))/(1000*60)));
                                                }

                                            }

                                            else {

                                                if(!is_off_day(dayName,thisDate.yyyymmdd())){

                                                    let _work_group_end_time = work_group_end_time;
                                                    if(dayName === 'Thursday'){
                                                        _work_group_end_time = work_group_thursday_end_time;
                                                    }


                                                    if(i === days){
                                                        if(end_time <= _work_group_end_time && end_time >=  work_group_start_time){
                                                            _work_group_end_time = end_time;
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    let _start_date = thisDate.yyyymmdd();
                                                    let _end_date = thisDate.yyyymmdd();


                                                    diffInM = ((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_end_time,_end_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_start_time,_start_date))/(1000*60));


                                                    console.log(_start_date+' '+work_group_start_time+' --- '+_end_date+' '+_work_group_end_time+' ---- '+((window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(_work_group_end_time,_end_date) - window.JSAPP.methods.parseTime(work_group_start_time,_start_date))/(1000*60)));
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if(diffInM > 0){
                                                max_off_time += diffInM;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if(max_off_time !== 0){
                                    vacationTime += max_off_time;
                                }

                                let calculate_vacation = window.JSAPP.methods.timeParser(vacationTime,9);

                                if(calculate_vacation.default_min >= min_vacation_time_in_minute){

                                    if(calculate_vacation.day > 0){
                                        $("#vacation_time_help").html('هر روز کاری برابر '+in_day_work_time+' ساعت');
                                    }

                                    if(calculate_vacation.default_min <= max_vacation_time_in_hour*60){
                                        time_input.val(calculate_vacation.string);
                                        time_input.removeClass('text-danger');
                                        time_input.addClass('text-success');
                                        submitButton.classList.remove("disabled");
                                        submitButton.disabled = false;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        time_input.val('حداکثر مرخصی '+max_vacation_time_in_hour+' ساعت');
                                        time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                                        time_input.addClass('text-danger');
                                        submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                                        submitButton.disabled = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    time_input.val('حداقل مرخصی '+min_vacation_time_in_minute+' دقیقه');
                                    time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                                    time_input.addClass('text-danger');
                                    submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                                    submitButton.disabled = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                                time_input.addClass('text-danger');
                                //زمان شروع باید کوچکتر از پایان باشد
                                time_input.val('بازه زمانی صحیحی انتخاب نشده است');
                                submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                                submitButton.disabled = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            time_input.val('');
                            time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                            time_input.removeClass('text-danger');
                            if(end_at && start_at){
                                time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                                time_input.addClass('text-danger');
                                time_input.val('حداقل مرخصی '+min_vacation_time_in_minute+' دقیقه');
                            }
                            else{
                                time_input.removeClass('text-success');
                                time_input.removeClass('text-danger');
                                time_input.val('');
                            }
                            submitButton.classList.add("disabled");
                            submitButton.disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

used window.JSAPP.methods.*

```
'use strict';
var JSAPP = {

    methods : {

        addDays: function (theDate, days) {
            if(typeof days === "undefined"){
                days = 1;
            }
            if(days == 0){
                return new Date(theDate.getTime());
            }
            else{
                return new Date(theDate.getTime() + parseInt(days) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        },

        dayName(dateString,format='string'){
            let safeDate
            if(format == 'string'){
                safeDate = this.getSafeDate(dateString);
            }
            else{
                safeDate = dateString;
            }

            let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
            let day = days[safeDate.getDay()];

            if(safeDate && day){
                return day;
            }
        },

        subDays: function (theDate, days) {
            if(typeof days === "undefined"){
                days = 1;
            }
            return new Date(theDate.getTime() - parseInt(days) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        },

        stringToTimestamp : function(datetime){

            if(!isNaN(new Date(datetime).getDate())){
                var arr_datetime;

                if(datetime.search("-") !== -1 && datetime.search(":") !== -1){
                    arr_datetime = datetime.split(/[- :]/);

                    var sec = '00';
                    if(typeof arr_datetime[5] !== 'undefined'){
                        sec = arr_datetime[5];
                    }

                    return parseInt(new Date(arr_datetime[0], arr_datetime[1]-1, arr_datetime[2], arr_datetime[3], arr_datetime[4], sec).getTime().toString());
                }
                else{
                    if(datetime.search("-") !== -1){
                        arr_datetime = datetime.split(/-/);
                        return parseInt(new Date(arr_datetime[0], arr_datetime[1]-1, arr_datetime[2]).getTime().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        diffInDay(start,end){

            var diffSec = Math.abs((end - start)/1000);

            var diffMin = Math.ceil((diffSec) / 60);

            var diffHrs = Math.ceil((diffSec) / 3600);

            var diffDay_one = Math.ceil(diffHrs/(24));
            var diffDay_two = Math.ceil(diffSec / (3600*24));
            var diffDay = Math.ceil(diffSec / (3600*24));

            return {
                second: diffSec,
                minute: diffMin,
                hour : diffHrs,
                day : diffDay,
                diffDay_one : diffDay_one,
                diffDay_two : diffDay_two,
            }
        },

        timeParser: function(min,oneDayH=24){

            var seconds = Number(min*60);
            var d = Math.floor(seconds / (3600*oneDayH));
            var h = Math.floor(seconds % (3600*oneDayH) / 3600);
            var m = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60);
            var s = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
            var result = '';

            // var dDisplay = d > 0 ? d + (d == 1 ? " day, " : " days, ") : "";
            // var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
            // var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
            // var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";

            var dDisplay = (d > 0 ? d : '');
            var hDisplay = (h > 0 ? h : '');
            var mDisplay = (m > 0 ? m : '');
            var sDisplay = (s > 0 ? s : '');


            if(dDisplay > 0){
                result += dDisplay+' روز';
            }

            if(hDisplay > 0 && dDisplay > 0){
                result += ' و '+hDisplay+' ساعت';
            }
            else if(hDisplay > 0 && dDisplay < 1){
                result += hDisplay+' ساعت';
            }

            if(mDisplay > 0 && hDisplay > 0){
                result += ' و '+mDisplay+' دقیقه';
            }
            else if(mDisplay > 0 && hDisplay < 1 && dDisplay < 1){
                result += mDisplay+' دقیقه';
            }
            else if(mDisplay > 0 && hDisplay < 1 && dDisplay > 0 ){
                result += ' و '+mDisplay+' دقیقه';
            }

            return {
                string : result,
                day    : dDisplay,
                hour   : hDisplay,
                minute : mDisplay,
                second : sDisplay,
                fullH : Math.ceil((min) / 60),
                default_min : min
            };

        },

        disabledDays : function(daysList){
            let result = [];
            if(daysList && daysList !== "undefined" && daysList.length > 0 && daysList != null && daysList != ''){
                for(let i = 0 ; i < daysList.length; i++){

                    if(daysList[i] == 'Saturday' || daysList[i] == 0 ){
                        result.push(0);
                    }
                    else if( daysList[i] == 'Sunday' || daysList[i] == 1){
                        result.push(1);
                    }
                    else if( daysList[i] == 'Monday' || daysList[i] == 2){
                        result.push(2);
                    }
                    else if(daysList[i] == 'Tuesday' || daysList[i] == 3){
                        result.push(3);
                    }
                    else if(daysList[i] == 'Wednesday' || daysList[i] == 4){
                        result.push(4);
                    }
                    else if(daysList[i] == 'Thursday' || daysList[i] == 5){
                        result.push(5);
                    }
                    else if(daysList[i] == 'Friday' || daysList[i] == 6){
                        result.push(6);
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        },

        disabledDates(ddates){
            let dates = ddates;
            let result = [];
            if(dates && dates !== "undefined" && dates.length > 0 && dates != null && dates != ''){

                if(!Array.isArray(ddates)){
                    if(this.canSplit(dates,',')) {
                        dates = dates.split(',');
                    }
                    else{
                        result.push(this.getSafeDate(dates));
                    }
                }
                for(let i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
                    result.push(this.getSafeDateSpliter(dates[i]));
                }
            }

            return result;
        },

        canSplit : function(str, token){
            return (str || '').split(token).length > 1;
        },

        getSafeDate: function(dateString){
            if(dateString != null && dateString != ''){
                let __start_at = null;
                var start_at = dateString;

                start_at = start_at.replace(/ /g,'');

                var arr_start_at = null;


                let _date = null;
                let __date = null;


                if(start_at.search("/") !== -1){

                    if(start_at.search(" ") !== -1){
                        _date = start_at.split(" ")[0].split("/");
                        __date = window.jalaali.toGregorian(parseInt(_date[0]), parseInt(_date[1]), parseInt(_date[2]));
                    }
                    else{
                        _date = start_at.split("/");
                        __date = window.jalaali.toGregorian(parseInt(_date[0]), parseInt(_date[1]), parseInt(_date[2]));
                    }

                    arr_start_at = parseInt(__date.gy) + '-' + ('0' + parseInt(__date.gm)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + parseInt(__date.gd)).slice(-2);
                }
                else{

                    arr_start_at = start_at;

                }

                arr_start_at = arr_start_at.split('-');


                __start_at =  new Date(parseInt(arr_start_at[0]), parseInt(arr_start_at[1])-1, parseInt(arr_start_at[2]));

                return __start_at;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        },

        getSafeDateSpliter: function(dateString){
            if(dateString != null && dateString != ''){
                let __start_at = null;
                let start_at = dateString.replace(/ /g,'');
                var arr_start_at = null;


                let _date = null;
                let __date = null;


                if(start_at.search("/") !== -1){

                    if(start_at.search(" ") !== -1){
                        _date = start_at.split(" ")[0].split("/");
                        __date = window.jalaali.toGregorian(parseInt(_date[0]), parseInt(_date[1]), parseInt(_date[2]));
                    }
                    else{
                        _date = start_at.split("/");
                        __date = window.jalaali.toGregorian(parseInt(_date[0]), parseInt(_date[1]), parseInt(_date[2]));
                    }

                    arr_start_at = parseInt(__date.gy) + '-' + ('0' + parseInt(__date.gm)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + parseInt(__date.gd)).slice(-2);
                }
                else{

                    arr_start_at = start_at;

                }

                arr_start_at = arr_start_at.split('-');


                __start_at =  new Date(parseInt(arr_start_at[0]), parseInt(arr_start_at[1])-1, parseInt(arr_start_at[2]));

                return __start_at;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        },

        parseTime: function(cTime,date=null) {
            if (cTime == '') return null;
            var d = new Date();
            if(date != null){
                d = new Date(date);
            }
            var time = cTime.match(/(\d+)(:(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/);
            d.setHours( parseInt(time[1]) + ( ( parseInt(time[1]) < 12 && time[4] ) ? 12 : 0) );
            d.setMinutes( parseInt(time[3]) || 0 );
            d.setSeconds(0, 0);
            return d;
        },

    }
};
```

finaly i write backend code for calculate agian serverside and insert row per day and create vacation table and vacation details table

Answer (score 2):

First, ignore the hours and calculate the difference in days between the two dates (Ignoring holidays as you pointed out).
`2021-12-25 ->  2021-12-29 = 4 days difference`. Multiply that amount by 9 hours, 4 * 9 = 36 hours.

You can also do some more arithmetic with the minutes if needed:
`(14:25:00 start, 15:00:00 end, would mean you do 36 - (25/60))`

Then when you want to show how many "days" the user has just divide back the hours by 9 and make sure to turn the decimals into minutes.

Comment: This depends on the start and end times being the same and doesn't deal with non–business days.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as simple as getting the time between two Dates.

You need to resolve whether the start time is before, during or after business hours on the start date, then work out the business hours for that day.

Then work out the business hours for each whole day up to, but not including, the last day.

Then calculate the business hours for the last day similarly to the first day, except you want the hours before the end date not after.

The result will then be the first day hours + intermediate hours + last day hours expressed as days and hours.

The following is a fairly simple implementation based on business hours being 8 to 17 Mon to Fri in whole hours. The intention is not to provide a robust solution for the OP's requirements but to explain the complexity and issues involved.

```js
// Return ISO week number as YYYY[W]WW, e.g. 2020W1
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117889/257182
function getWeekNumber(d) {
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay()||7));
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
    return `${d.getUTCFullYear()}W${(''+weekNo).padStart(2,'0')}`;
}

// Assume business days are Monday to Friday
// If start time is not 00:00:00, count from start of next day
// If end time is not 00:00:00, count to start of day
// Part days must be handled by caller
function getWholeBusinessDays(start, end) {
  // end must be >= start
  if (end < start) return;
  // Helper - set Sat or Sun to Mon
  let setToMon = d => d.setDate(d.getDate() + (d.getDay() == 6? 2 : 1));
  
  let s = new Date(+start),
      e = new Date(+end),
      days = 0;
  // If s doesn't start at midnight, set to end of day
  if (s.setHours(0,0,0,0) != +start) s.setHours(24);
  // Set e to start of day
  e.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // If s is on a weekend, set to Monday
  if (!(s.getDay() % 6)) setToMon(s);
  // If e is on a weekend, set to Monday
  if (!(e.getDay() % 6)) setToMon(e);
  
  // If s and e are same week, get days between them
  if (getWeekNumber(s) == getWeekNumber(e)) {
    return e.getDay() - s.getDay();
  // Otherwise get days from s to end of week +
  // days from start of week to e + 5 * weeks between
  } else {
    days += 6 - s.getDay() + e.getDay() - 1;
    weeks = (Math.floor((e - s) / (7 * 8.64e7)));
    // If s.weekday on or before e.weekday, have too many weeks
    if (s.getDay() <= e.getDay()) --weeks;
    // Add weeks to days
    days += weeks * 5;
  }
  return days;
}

// Get leave as [days, hours] between two dates
// Business hours are 8 to 17 Mon to Fri
// Only whole hours considered
// If start or end day hours not zero, only business hours on that day are counted
// If end day is 00:00, counts as whole day (i.e. inclusive)
function getLeave(start, end) {
  // end must be >= start
  if (end < start) return;
  // Helper - set Sat or Sun to Mon
  let setToMon = d => d.setDate(d.getDate() + (d.getDay() == 6? 2 : 1));
  let setToDayStart = d => d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let setToDayEnd   = d => d.setHours(24,0,0,0);
  // Setup
  let s = new Date(+start),
      e = new Date(+end),
      hours = 0,
      days = 0;
  // Move weekends to start of Monday
  if (!(s.getDay() %6)) {
    setToMon(s);
    setToDayStart(s);
  }
  if (!(e.getDay() %6)) {
    setToMon(e);
    setToDayStart(e);
  }
  // If start not 00:00, get hours and set to next day
  if (s.getHours()) {
    if (s.getHours() < 8) {
      s.setHours(8);
    }
    if (s.getHours() < 17) {
      hours += 17 - s.getHours();
    }
    // Accounted for start day hours so set to next day
    setToDayEnd(s);
  }
  // If end not 00:00, get hours and set to start of day
  if (e.getHours() > 17) {
    e.setHours(17);
  }
  if (e.getHours() > 8) {
    hours += e.getHours() - 8;
  }
  setToDayStart(e);
  
  // If hours are more than 9, add excess to days
  if (hours > 8) {
    days += Math.floor(hours / 9);
    hours = hours % 9;
  }

  // Add business days between dates
  days += getWholeBusinessDays(s, e);
  
  // If original end was a business day and 00:00,
  // include it
  if (end.getDay() % 6 && end.getHours() == 0) {
    ++days;
  }
  
  return [days, hours];  
}

// Examples
[[new Date(2022,0, 3, 0), new Date(2022,0, 3, 0)], // Mon to Mon 1 day
 [new Date(2022,0, 3, 0), new Date(2022,0, 4,12)], // Mon to Tue noon 1 day, 4 hours
 [new Date(2022,0, 3, 0), new Date(2022,0, 4, 0)], // Mon to Tue 2 days
 [new Date(2022,0, 7, 0), new Date(2022,0,10, 0)], // Fri to Mon 2 days
 [new Date(2022,0, 7,12), new Date(2022,0,10,12)], // Fri noon to Mon noon
 [new Date(2022,0, 7,12), new Date(2022,0,17,12)], // Fri noon to Mon noon + 1 week
 [new Date(2022,0, 4, 0), new Date(2022,0, 6, 0)], // Tue to Thu 3 days
 [new Date(2022,0, 6, 0), new Date(2022,0,18, 0)], // Thu to Tue + week 9 days
].forEach(([s, e]) => {
  let [days, hours] = getLeave(s, e); 
  console.log(`${s.toString().substr(0,21)} - ${e.toString().substr(0,21)} ` +
              `${days} day${days == 1? '':'s'} ${hours} hour${hours == 1? '':'s'}`);
})
```