# Weekly counter with text display

Tags: javascript, counter, week-number

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErEyR.png)[A screenshot of website interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKZda.png)My day will be made more beautiful if I get some assistance. Using JavaScript or any other language is there a way I can develop a weekly counter that will display certain text per week, for instance, Week1 - Algeria, Week 2 - South Africa down to week 52 on a website I am developing

Still making research regarding this, no-coding trial yet

Comment: You can start by [getting the number of a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php) and use that to index an array of "week names"

Comment: What do you mean by "no code trial"?

Answer (score -1):

You can start by [getting the number of a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php) and use that to index an array of "week names", or also use a [time library](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve the same goal. The following code uses the former:

```js
/* For a given date, get the ISO week number */
function getWeekNumber(d) {
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay()||7));
    // Get first day of year
    const yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    const weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
    // Return array of year and week number
    return [d.getUTCFullYear(), weekNo];
}

const weekNames = ["Morocco", "South Africa", ...]
const currentWeek = getWeekNumber(new Date())

const formattedText = `Week${currentWeek}: ${weekNames[currentWeek]}`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and assistance, I appreciate 

Comment: There was a space to enter attempted  code, so I replied No code trial

Comment: I have tried using the second approach when I copy and paste I get an error message   const weekNames = ["Morocco", "South Africa", ...]
const currentWeek = getWeekNumber(new Date())

const formattedText = `Week${currentWeek}: ${weekNames[currentWeek]}`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I will forward a screenshot through a link on the main question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErEyR.png here is a link to the screenshot

Comment: The first code with the function didn't show error message but applying it to display countries might be a challenge, I will be glad if I can find a way around it.

Comment: The second seem very straightforward