# Add random number to array and appear on site

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hopefully some can help or advise.
I am working in javascript and have code that will pick a random number for me but I need to store that number each week plus not have the code pick that same number the next week. Plus I will want the number that is picked each week to be displayed on the website.

As it stand the code picks the random number but the array keeps giving me multiple numbers not the storing the one that the function picked for me.

```
function getRndId() {


return Math.floor(Math.random() * (0, 5554));
}




document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = getRndId();




const IdArray = [];
for (let i = -1; i<getRndId(); i++) {
  if (!IdArray.includes(getRndId())) {
    IdArray.push(getRndId());
  }
}

document.getElementById("Picked_numbers").innerHTML = IdArray;
```

Comment: Hi Kris, can you please tell us what your question is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the JavaScript `Math.random()` is not seedable. Thanks to David Bau's [seedrandom.js](http://davidbau.com/encode/seedrandom.js) library you can now seed the random number generation and thereby make it reproducible. The most effective way of avoiding repetitions in a random number sequence is to work with a shuffled array. In the following snippet I am using a Durstenfeld shuffle.

The week number within the current year can be calculated via [getWeekNumber(d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php):

```js
function shuffle(a){  // Durstenfeld shuffle
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}
function getWeekNumber(d) { // get current week within calendar year
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay()||7));
    // Get first day of year
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
    // return year-2020 and week number as an array
    return [d.getFullYear()-2020,weekNo];
}

Math.seedrandom("start"); // random sequence is now reproducible!
const [year,wk]=getWeekNumber(new Date()), week=53*year+wk,
  arr=shuffle([...Array(5555).keys()].slice(1)); // array with 5554 elements

console.log(`Last week's random number is ${arr[week-1]}.`);
console.log(`The random number for week no ${wk} is ${arr[week]}.`);
console.log(`Next week's random number is ${arr[week+1]}.`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.3.10/seedrandom.min.js"></script>
```

Some further detail:

The function `getWeekNumber()` returns an array with two numbers: the current year-2020 (`year`) and the number of the week within the current year (`wk`). I chose to combine the two numbers by multiplying the first by 53 and adding the second one. This gives me a reproducible week number of any week after 1 Jan 2020 which I store in the constant `week`:

```
const [year,wk]=getWeekNumber(new Date()), week=53*year+wk
```

`arr[week]` is the element with index `week` of the array `arr`, the shuffled sequence-number-array of 5554 elements. With this array I can safely generate reproducible random numbers for each week in a period of more than 100 years - without repetition.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I'll give it a go see if I can integrate it.